# How to test for stdout that is inside a .each iteration block, using rspec?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, iteration, stdout

I have a sample code:

```
  def print_stuff(first_num, second_num)
    puts 'hello'
    (first_num..second_num).to_a.each do |num|
      puts 'The current number is: '
      puts "#{num}"
    end
  end
```

I and using rspec, I would like to test to see if the output is correct or not. My attempt are as follows:

```
  expect(initialize_program(1, 3)).to output(
    "The current number is: 
    1
    The current number is: 
    2
    The current number is: 
    3").to_stdout
```

But instead, I get a expected block to output to stdout but not a block error since the initialize_program(1,3) is outputting the texts, but it is done inside a .each block thus the method itself returns the array of range of numbers.

How can I test for the texts inside the block, to see if the outputted texts are correct?

Thanks!

Comment: where is your `initialize_program` method, please put it there.

Comment: Sorry, the initialize_program is actually supposed to be the print_stuff method above. But I have solved it. I just catched the STDOUT from the console and converted into a string, and tested  that. Thanks though,

Comment: you need to pass a block to `expect` if you want to use `output` matcher, so I think changing to `expect { print_stuff(1, 3) }.to output(...)` should work for you (note the curly braces)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65135207/1301972

Comment: @StefanRendevski The [output_to_stdout matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-10/docs/built-in-matchers/output-matcher#output-to-stdout-matcher) will work, but in this case it feels like an anti-pattern. Refactoring the method to be more easily testable, rather than parsing standard output, seems like a cleaner approach. The matcher is certainly a viable option, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Todd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65238696/299774) is fine and I'd strongly recommend you read it carefully: refactor your app in a way that UI (CLI in your case) is minimal and easy to test. But when you want full coverage you'd need to test that std output eventually.

The way you're using it now:

```
expect(initialize_program(1, 3)).to output("whatever").to_stdout
```

Means that `initialize_program(1, 3)` is evaluated immediately when the matcher is called, and it's too soon - it has to do it's magic(*) first, and then run your code. Try like this:

```
expect { initialize_program(1, 3) }.to output("whatever").to_stdout
```

Now, instead passing results of calling `initialize_program(1, 3)` into the matcher, you pass a block that "knows how" to call `initialize_program(1, 3)`. So what the matcher does:

1. [saves the block for later](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/44d90f46a2654ffeab3ba65eff243039232802ce/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/output.rb#L18)
2. does it magic to capture whatever goes to the STDOUT (see below)
3. [calls the block](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/44d90f46a2654ffeab3ba65eff243039232802ce/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/output.rb#L20), calling the `initialize_program(1, 3)`, capturing whatever was supposed to go to STDOUT
4. [compares it](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/44d90f46a2654ffeab3ba65eff243039232802ce/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/output.rb#L21) with what you've set up in your expectation (the `output("whatever")` part)

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/output-matcher

- The mentioned magic is not that magical anyway:

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/44d90f46a2654ffeab3ba65eff243039232802ce/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/output.rb#L49
and
https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/44d90f46a2654ffeab3ba65eff243039232802ce/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/output.rb#L141

It just creates StringIO, and replaces global var $stdout with it.

Answer (score 0):

### Refactor to Inspect a String, *Not* Standard Output

This type of code is why you should write your tests *first*. You're essentially testing Kernel#puts, which always returns `nil`, rather than validating that you've constructed the String you expect. Don't do that. Instead, refactor like so:

```rb
def print_stuff(num1, num2)
  str =
    (num1..num2).map { |num|"The current number is: #{num}" }
    .join "\n"
  puts str
  str
end

print_stuff 1, 3
#=> "The current number is: 1\nThe current number is: 2\nThe current number is: 3"
```

This will not only print what you expect on standard output:

> ```
> The current number is: 1
> The current number is: 2
> The current number is: 3
> ```

but will also use the implicit return of the last line of your method to return a value that you can use to compare to the expectations in your spec.

You might also refactor the method to return an Array of String objects, or whatever else you might explicitly want to test. The more your real method reflects what you plan to test, the better.

### RSpec Examples

```rb
RSpec.describe '#print_stuff' do
  it 'prints the expected message' do
    expected_string = <<~EOF
      The current number is: 1
      The current number is: 2
      The current number is: 3
    EOF
    expect(print_stuff 1, 3).to eql(expected_string.chomp)
  end

  # Even without the collection matchers removed in RSpec 3,
  # you can still validate the number of items returned.
  it 'returns the expected number of lines' do
    lines = print_stuff(1, 3).split("\n").count
    expect(lines).to eql(3)
  end
end
```

#### Testing RSpec Examples in IRB

In irb, you can validate your specs like so:

```rb
require 'rspec'
include RSpec::Matchers

expected_string = <<~EOF
  The current number is: 1
  The current number is: 2
  The current number is: 3
EOF

# String#chomp is needed to strip the newline from the
# here-document
expect(print_stuff 1, 3).to eql(expected_string.chomp)

# test the returned object in other ways, if you want
lines = print_stuff(1, 3).split("\n").count
expect(lines).to eql(3)
```